# Serve static files from cloudfront CDN with nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, redirect, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have set a CDN with amazon cloudfront for my website. I now have files on my cdn with the same location of folders in my website.

I tried using a plugin to setup cdn for my website but it didn't work as expected.

So now I am trying to setup nginx to server the files from my CDN(an external URL). I have seen several posts for this but none of them worked for me.

this is what i have done so far

```
location ~* \.(gif|png|jpg|svg|woff|js|css)$ {

             rewrite ^ https://mycdnurl.net$request_uri permanent;
             proxy_pass https://mycdnurl.net;

       }
```

both didn't work.

To simply help

https://mywesite.com/images/abcd.jpg should become https://mycdnurl.net/images/abcd.jpg

and the path for the file can be anything and is not constant.

any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the second block. The first block contains two conflicting directives. If you want to redirect to your CDN, you should use:

```
location ~* \.(gif|png|jpg|svg|woff|js|css)$ {
    return 301 https://mycdnurl.net$request_uri;
}
```

Which is just a simplified version of your `rewrite ^ https://mycdnurl.net$request_uri permanent;` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

If that does not work, you need to update your question with more details of the problem.

*Thanks to Michael for pointing out that the above scheme will only work if CloudFront is not using this server and the same URI to obtain its authoritative copy.*

Comment: Either this server is handling requests for `mycdnurl.net`, or `mycdnurl.net` is redirecting back to this server. You could look at the HTTP headers and establish the cause of the loop.

Comment: yes requests from cdn are getting redirect back to the website url

Comment: @RichardSmith I'll say you are doing phenomenally well on trying to answer this without (I suspect) one critical piece of info... CloudFront doesn't host content.  OP says the files are "on" the CDN, which isn't possible -- CloudFront is a caching, pull-through CDN.  It will proxy every request *somewhere authoritative* if it's for a file that it hasn't already cached, so it can cache the content for next time. There must be an authoritative source of the content in another service or system, such as S3, or on the app server itself, in which case, redirection of direct-only requests is needed.

Comment: ...and for all we can tell at this point, this server is trying to proxy requests over to CloudFront, which is already trying to proxy requests back to here.